# SpringBoot MongoDB: how to find the CLOSEST POSITIVE DIFF document?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Considering a collection with the following documents:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f984d04093a1a0be1237db2"),
    "postalCode" : "",
    "latitude" : -33.4939994812012,
    "longitude" : 143.210403442383,
    "accuracyRadius" : 1000,
    "network" : "1.0.0.0/24",
    "geoNameID" : 2077456,
    "registeredCountryGeoNameID" : 2077456,
    "anonymousProxy" : false,
    "satelliteProvider" : false,
    "_class" : "project.domain.maxmind.block.GeoLite2CityBlockIPv4"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f984d04093a1a0be1237db3"),
    "postalCode" : "",
    "latitude" : 34.7724990844727,
    "longitude" : 113.726600646973,
    "accuracyRadius" : 50,
    "network" : "1.0.1.0/24",
    "geoNameID" : 1814991,
    "registeredCountryGeoNameID" : 1814991,
    "anonymousProxy" : false,
    "satelliteProvider" : false,
    "_class" : "project.domain.maxmind.block.GeoLite2CityBlockIPv4"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f984d04093a1a0be1237db4"),
    "postalCode" : "",
    "latitude" : 34.7724990844727,
    "longitude" : 113.726600646973,
    "accuracyRadius" : 50,
    "network" : "1.0.2.0/23",
    "geoNameID" : 1814991,
    "registeredCountryGeoNameID" : 1814991,
    "anonymousProxy" : false,
    "satelliteProvider" : false,
    "_class" : "project.domain.maxmind.block.GeoLite2CityBlockIPv4"
}]
```

How can I write an efficient query for the closest network, starting from an IP address (string) as the input?

E.g. considering the network `1.0.1.0/24`
[image]

and the IPv4 `1.0.1.200`

[image]

I should convert the IPv4 to its corresponding integer value

`1.0.1.200` --> `16777672`

and do the same for each network

```
network 1.0.0.0/24 --> 16777216
host min 1.0.0.1 --> 16777217
host max 1.0.0.254 --> 16777470

network 1.0.1.0/24 --> 16777472
host min 1.0.1.1 --> 16777473
host max 1.0.1.254 --> 16777726

network 1.0.2.0/23 --> 16777728
host min 1.0.2.1 --> 16777729
host max 1.0.3.254 --> 16778238
```

Then I would need to do a diff among the IP and the network to find the closest positive one:

```
16777672 - 16777216 = 456
16777672 - 16777472 = 200
16777672 - 16777728 = -56
```

How could I write such a query, considering that both the IPs and networks are Strings?
I could do just the conversion of the IP to its integer value, before passing it to the `@Repository`, but then I would need to convert the network addresses inside the `@Query`.

```
@Repository
public interface GeoLite2CityBlockIPv4Repository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<GeoLite2CityBlockIPv4, BigInteger>, ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor<GeoLite2CityBlockIPv4> {
    Mono<GeoLite2CityBlockIPv4> findOneByNetwork(String network);

    @Query("{?}")
    Mono<GeoLite2CityBlockIPv4> findOneByIP(Integer ip);
}
```

Comment: What is the source of the `IPv4`? Is it another collection?

Comment: The input IPv4 is from an API endpoint

Comment: You build a repository aggregation query; and aggregation has operators to convert the string to integer values, perform comparisons and return a result. See `@org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Aggregation`.

Comment: At the moment I'm using two additional fields (minIP, maxIP) with the corresponding BigInteger values. Hence the query is as simple as below and moreover the values are computed just once.
<br/>
`@Query("{'minIP' : {$lte: ?0}, 'maxIP' : {$gte: ?0}}")
Mono<GeoLite2CityBlockIPv4> findOneByIP(BigInteger ip);`

Comment: You can build an aggregation query (instead of @Query), _or_ provide an implementation for the `Query` which can have the _logic_ of your requirement.